# The easiest way to serve an existing and working (staticfile) Angular App to nodejs

Tags: node.js, angular

I have an Angular App running on CloudFoundry. Now, because I need special SDKs which are only available over NodeJS I am looking for the easiest way to run the Angular App on NodeJS. Since I dont know much about Node, i am asking if there is an easy an fast way to run a node server with the angular app.

Comment: What's an example use case with the special SDK? Could you spin up a separate API service instead of coupling your front end to a Node http server?

Comment: I want to get access to the MindSphere API. Target is to get Infos from the logged in users. (MindSphere is an IIOT-OS build up on CloudFoundry)